# Keeping some data from duplicates and adding to existing python dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, duplicates, nested-loops, data-cleaning

I have an issue with **keeping some data** from duplicates and wanting to add valuable information to a new column in the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id':[1,1,2,2,3],'key':[1,1,2,2,1],'value0':['a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'a']}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id','key','value0'])
print frame
```

Yields:

```
    id   key   value0
0   1    1     a
1   1    1     b
2   2    2     x
3   2    2     y
4   3    1     a
```

Desired Output:

```
    key   value0_0  value0_1    value1_0  
0   1     a         b           a
1   2     x         y           None
```

*The "id" column isn't important to keep but could help with iteration and grouping.*

I think this could be adapted to other projects where you don't know how many values exist for a set of keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_index` including a `cumcount` and `unstack`

```
frame.set_index(
    ['key', frame.groupby('key').cumcount()]
).value0.unstack().add_prefix('value0_').reset_index()

   key value0_0 value0_1 value0_2
0    1        a        b        a
1    2        x        y     None
```

---

I'm questioning your column labeling but here is an approach using binary

```
frame.set_index(
        ['key', frame.groupby('key').cumcount()]
    ).value0.unstack().rename(
    columns='{:02b}'.format
).add_prefix('value_').reset_index()

   key value_00 value_01 value_10
0    1        a        b        a
1    2        x        y     None
```

Comment: Thank you @moondra

Comment: This is elegant !

Comment: Indeed! Thank you @piRSquared! You solved the question however the solution didn't quite fix my original problem on my dataframe. I'll have to ask in a better way. Stay tuned ;)